# Git Bash issue when 'Entering interactive session'. (Windows 10)

Tags: ssh, cmd, windows-10, git-bash, mintty

SSH used to work nicely with Git Bash before. Don't know what happened recently.

SSH version on CMD:

```
C:\Users\ my-user>ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

Debug/errors On CMD:

```
C:\Users\ my-user>ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

C:\Users\ my-user>ssh -v my-user1@server-url
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug1: Connecting to server-url [public-ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to server-url:22 as 'my-user1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Mw4Mlvqk2MgCynA+8nTUrxDy8wxXONlTAVk2K/FgbcQ
debug1: Host 'server-url' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/known_hosts:167
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server-url ([public-ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_INPUT is supported. Reading the VTSequence from console
debug1: ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING is supported. Console supports the ansi parsing
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
Last login: Tue Jun 28 09:20:50 2022 from org-ip
```

Same SSH version on Git Bash:

```
 my-user@my-server MINGW64 /
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

Debug/errors On Git Bash:

```
 my-user@my-server MINGW64 /
$ ssh -v my-user1@server-url
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
debug1: Connecting to server-url [public-ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to server-url:22 as 'my-user1'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:Mw4Mlvqk2MgCynA+8nTUrxDy8wxXONlTAVk2K/FgbcQ
debug1: Host 'server-url' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/known_hosts:167
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
Authorized uses only. All activity may be monitored and reported.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\ my-user/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:OyvnNnesOb+dn3j9NWl9dkDu/Fi52CKlN9Vq8h9LzoA
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to server-url ([public-ip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
<gets stuck here>
```

Any help/leads is welcome
Note: Git Bash uses mintty terminal

Comment: found a workaround: SSH works if I select "Windows cmd" as terminal instead of "mintty" which is the default while installation.

Comment: add `wintpy` before any interactive command and run from gitbash. Your command will become `wintpy ssh -v my-user1@server-url`

Answer (score 0):

found a workaround solution: SSH works if I select "Windows cmd" as terminal instead of "mintty" which is the default while installation